# Decorating a generator in Python: call some method in between yields

Tags: python, generator, decorator

I found some very useful information about decorating generator functions in Python [here](https://github.com/universe-proton/universe-topology/issues/5) using `yield from`. For example:

```
def mydec(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Getting values from "{func.__name__}"...')
        x = yield from func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f'Got value {x}')
        return x
    return wrapper

@mydec
def mygen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i
```

However, this seems to only allow for adding decorated behaviors at the beginning and end of the generator's lifetime:

```
>>> foo = mygen(3)
>>> x = next(foo)
Getting values from "mygen"...
>>> x
0
>>> x = next(foo)
>>> x
1
>>> x = next(foo)
>>> x
2
>>> x = next(foo)
Got value None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> x
2
```

However I am interested in using the decorator to implement some behavior every time the generator yields. However, the decorator should not modify the values that are gotten from the generator. That is, for example, I'd like to have the output:

```
>>> foo = mygen(3)
>>> x = next(foo)
Getting values from "mygen"...
Got value 0
>>> x
0
>>> x = next(foo)
Got value 1
>>> x
1
>>> x = next(foo)
Got value 2
>>> x
2
```

So, a call to `print` occurs with each yield, however the yielded values remain unchanged.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yield from` is for coroutine stuff.  You're not doing coroutine stuff. Just iterating the generator:

```
def mydec(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Getting values from "{func.__name__}"...')
        gen = func(*args, **kwargs)
        for value in gen:
            print(f'got value {value}')
            yield value
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not quite clear in my question. I don't want the string to be the return value, I simply want some behavior, for example the `print` statement, to run each time the generator yields. However, the values returned by `next()` should not be modified by the decorator.

Comment: OK, right, I see you edited the question.  Well now it's ever easier - that's just a plain old for-loop.