# How to apply decorators to an arbitrary function and call it inside the closure?

Tags: python, generics, closures, decorator, python-decorators

I was learning about how to use decorators in Python and as a practice, I made a decorator function that can print the execution time of a function it decorates. To do this, I had to call the decorated function in the closure function, which is where I had a problem. My code looks like this:

```
import time
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")

def print_elapsed_time(func: typing.Callable[..., T]) -> typing.Callable[..., typing.Any]:
    def closure() -> T:
        start: float = time.time()
        returnValue: T = func()
        end: float = time.time()
        print(end - start)
        return returnValue
    return closure

@print_elapsed_time
def foo() -> int:
    print("foo")
    return 1

i: int = foo()
print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
foo
0.0
1
```

As you can see, I can only call `func` inside `closure` only if `foo` has 0 arguments. So my question is: is it possible to modify `print_elapsed_time` so that it will work correctly no matter what function it decorates and call the decorated function with the originally supplied arguments? What I mean is that if `foo` accepts 1 `int` argument, how do I modify `print_elapsed_time` so that when I write for example `foo(10)`, the call to `func` inside `closure` can "adapt" to that and call `func(10)?`

Another strange problem is that at line 6, Pylance gives me this error:

```
TypeVar "T" appears only once in generic function signature
```

But I need to use `T` inside `print_elapsed_time` to know what to return. Is this an error caused by Plyance because it doesn't look into function bodies or is there some way to fix this error?

Comment: unrelated: for measuring durations is the `time.monotonic()` better than `time.time()`

Comment: Though my comment is not relevant, I m curious to know why you are using type casting, instead of taking advantage of pythons dynamic type casting, what advantages you are able to get by doing so?

Comment: @SanthoshReddy What do you mean? I'm not casting anything. I just use type hints because it reduces the chances of bugs.

Comment: @SanthoshReddy The OP is not performing type casting anywhere, but is simply adding type hints to allow static type checkers to warn developers if values of incompatible types are passed or assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `closure` function take variable arguments and variable keyword arguments, and pass them to the call to `func`:

```
def closure(*args, **kwargs) -> T:
    start: float = time.time()
    returnValue: T = func(*args, **kwargs)
    end: float = time.time()
    print(end - start)
    return returnValue
```

To answer the second question of yours, since the decorator should return a function that returns the same type as that of the returning value of the function that's passed to the decorator, you should specify the returning type of `print_elapsed_time` to be a callable that returns the type `T` instead of `Any`:

```
def print_elapsed_time(func: typing.Callable[..., T]) -> typing.Callable[..., T]:
```

Comment: What should I type the `*args` and `**kwargs`? I'm using `Any` but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @palapapa You can use `Any` to type hint `args` and `kwargs` in your case, since the decorator is meant to be generic. See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values

Comment: To my knowledge, the `**kwargs` is a `dict`, so if I annotate it to be `Any`, does that mean only the values are `Any` and the keys are `str`, or are they both `Any`?

Comment: For variable arguments and keyword arguments, as the PEP documentation in the above link shows, type hints apply to the values of the containers, not the containers themselves. Since the keys of `kwargs` are always `str`, only the values are worth type hinting.

Comment: Can we also use `yield` instead of `return` inside closure and then do `print(end-start)`?

Comment: Yes you can. Please give it a try. An example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106140/decorating-a-generator-in-python-call-some-method-in-between-yields